# Flex builder and multiple and potentially duplicated projects in the same work space?

Tags: flexbuilder

Is it possible have two projects with the same name in flex builder?

Here is the scenario

~/projects/myprojectdev/ProjectName

~/projects/myprojectstable/ProjectName

myprojectdev

and

myprojectstable

are more or less the same tree structure and duplicates of the same codebase.

I am using git to manage them as separate repositories. I can do some stuff in the **myprojectdev** folder and then occasionally merge changes over to the **myprojectstable** folder when I am satisfied. But I want to keep code from **myprojectstable** in my working space in flex builder to be able to launch it and occasionally compare the code between dev and stable. I may also want to open different versions of the same project codebase and compare them in the working environment. The problem is that in both folders the "**ProjectName**" is the same. And so I can't import both into my Flex Builder workspace. I get the warning

> A project with the same name already
>   exists in your workspace. Rename or
>   delete the existing project.

But I don't want to rename the project or mess with its folder structure. What do I do? Do I have to keep these in different folders? e.g.

~/projects/myprojectdev/ProjectNameDev

~/projects/myprojectstable/ProjectNameStable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rename a project (in eclipse/flex builder) without actually renaming the folder it is in. Edit the `.project` file in your ProjectNameDev and ProjectNameDev to give the projects different names. You might need to restart eclipse to get it to recognize the new name.